# IO redirection with exec

Tags: c, io, dup2

I'm trying to use files as input and output of program, but that don't working - the output file is empty

```
  int in = open(configuration->inPath, O_RDONLY);
  int out = open(outPutFile, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR| S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);

  pid_t  child = fork();
  if(child == 0) {
      dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
      close(in);
      dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
      close(out);
      execvp(execFile, NULL);
      exit(0);
  }
```

the execFile is work. Do you have any idea?
thank you!

Comment: You need to verify that `open` succeeded. `open` returns -1 when it fails, and you can use `perror` to print an error message if that happens.

Comment: I'm also not convinced that passing `NULL` as the second argument to `execvp` is legal. Putting a `perror` after `execvp` will help diagnose that.

Comment: It is unusual to let group and others write to a file even though they're not permitted to read it.  I'd expect you to use `S_IRUSR| S_IRGRP | S_IRGRP | S_IRUSR` (or even 0644, which is a whole lot more readable to my eyes), though if you use `umask 022` (as I do), neither group nor others would have any access to the created file anyway.

Comment: How do you know that the `execvp()` works?  You use `exit(0)` immediately after it, which signals success on failure (because `execvp()` only returns if it fails).  You don't print any error message before exiting, either.  The fact that you get an empty output file suggests you're running into problems somewhere.  The NULL pointer to `execvp()` could be a source of trouble.  You should normally have an array `char *args[] = { … };` or equivalent, and you then use `execvp(args[0], args);`.

Comment: the problem was in the execvp, as you said. thank you all!